# Accessing variables from other class in console application c#

Tags: c#

I cannot seem to figure out the following:
For a school project i need to run a simple program. The program has to be a console application. But i need to have a few classes, from which i need to refference a variable from the main class.

```
class Program
{
    public K[] ksmall = new K[number];
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         //do somethings with ksmall
    }
}

class K
{
   //something
}

class A
{
    public void SomethingElse()
    {
        //do something with ksmall
    }
}
```

I hope my example makes sense. So anyway, how can i acces the ksmall from class A. When i start creating instances of Program, i get null references. is there any possible way to make both classes acces the **same** ksmall?

Comment: Given `ksmall` is not static you would need an instance of `Program` to access it, or pass the `ksmall` reference to the `A.SomethingElse` (`public void SomethingElse(K[] ksmall)`)

Comment: How about passing ksmall as a parameter to that _SomethingElse_ method of A?

Comment: by default in C# if you do not specify the access level of the method it's default is `private` read up on Static vs Instance as well

Comment: The easiest way to do it is pass ksmall to SomethingElse (or "A" in a constructor).  If you pass it as a reference, you can modify it, or return the value from SomethingElse  e.g. K[] SomethingElse(K[] value) { return value; }

Comment: The problem is that i need to moddify the same ksmall in both classes. So making an instance of the program class makes the ksmall in one case null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ksmall is a **non-static** variable, so a static function (Main in your case) can't access it.
So, you can declare ksmall as **static**:

**public static K[] ksmall = new K[number];**

So now you can access ksmall from Main function as well as from other class functions as "**Program.ksmall**".

Comment: Yes thank you, I had it static in my project, but didnt have it public, i forgot you could have both. Thanks, it works now

Answer (score 0):

You should re-think about the architecture of your project, for example some [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) principles will give you more tools. I would recommend having your classes designed that you can either pass the object you want to share by a parameter in a constructor or in your methods. Another thing be careful with the encapsulation of your classes (private is by default, public anyone, protected inside the same namespace, private).

I hope this help you to get more understanding of the problem no the symptom.

Comment: with passing i would just change the passed ksmall, adn i would then have to update the program one, which would take up too much time, and my program has a time limit. Should i use ref then? because I'm not that familiar with ref

Comment: In C# all the objects are by reference, in your case in your methods you can pass the parameter (C# always pass a reference), or return the object in the method and re-assign it back. Whichever is better and faster for you.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to go about it.
First is that you could make a third, static class to hold ksmall (and any other variables you want to access from anywhere in the future)

```
class Program
{
    public K[] ksmall = new K[number];
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        VariableHolder.ksmall = new K[0];
    }
}

public class K
{
    //something
}

public class A
{
    public void SomethingElse()
    {
        //do something with ksmall
    }
}

public static class VariableHolder
{
    public static K[] ksmall = new K[number];
}
```

The other option is the pass ksmall into the method within the class as a parameter.

```
    class Program
    {
      public K[] ksmall = new K[number];
      static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             A classAInstance = new A();
             classAInstance.SomethingElse(ksmall);
        }
    }

   class K
    {
        //something
    }

    class A
    {
        public void SomethingElse(K[] kSmall)
        {
                kSmall[1] = new K();
            //do something with ksmall
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to make the class K public.

```
public class K
{
   //something
}
```

Comment: How would this help reference an instance variable in a static method?